# Resize polygon map R

Tags: r, dictionary

I am trying to scale a polygon map of the country of the world

```
mp <- map("world", plot = FALSE, fill=FALSE,interior = FALSE)
lpolygon(mp$x, mp$y, fill=TRUE, col=NA)
```

Is there a way of doing it in R?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you want to do? Do you want to make a polygon map of countries of the world?

Comment: Yes but a want to be able to scale it according to a parameter

Comment: If you want to *zoom* your map, then you can do so by `map("world", xlim=c(-140,-110),ylim=c(48,64), fill=TRUE, col="grey")` (for example). Or what do you mean by scale?

Comment: I mean resize it, thanks